# How were Athena and Ares worshipped in relation to war?

Tags: greek, athena, ares

#### Ares and Athena are both gods of war.

About [Athena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena):

> Athena is the goddess of wisdom, courage, inspiration, civilization, law and justice, mathematics, strength, **war strategy**, the arts, crafts, and skill in ancient Greek religion and mythology.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena)</sub>

About [Ares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares):

> Ares is the **Greek god of war**. He is one of the Twelve Olympians, and the son of Zeus and Hera. In Greek literature, he often represents the physical or violent and untamed aspect of war, in contrast to his sister the armored Athena, whose functions as a goddess of intelligence include military strategy and generalship.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares)</sub>

Since both gods represent war, **how are they different in relation to that? Is there any case where these two gods would come in conflict with one-another?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Those two gods were worshipped differently.

> Η Αθηνά, η οποία ξεκίνησε ως πάνοπλη Θεά του πολέμου και στη συνέχεια εξελίχθηκε σε πολιούχο Θεά της Αθήνας και σύμβολο της σοφίας, (...) Ο αιμοδιψής Άρης ήταν πολεμικός θεός, ο οποίος εκπροσωπούσε τη μανία και το παράλογο του πολέμου.
>
> ---
>
> Athena, who initially was an armed Goddess of War and then became a patron goddess of Athens and a symbol of wisdom, (...) 
>   The bloodthirsty Ares was a war god, who represented the fury and the absurdity of war.
>
> <sub>[Ekivolos.gr](http://www.ekivolos.gr/H%20thrhskeia%20twn%20arxaiwn%20ellhnwn.htm)</sub>

While both gods are representantives of war, [Ares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares) actually represented the violence of war, while [Athena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena) was believed to have taught the Greek warriors the the art of war.

> Η μαχητική φύση της Αθηνάς εξαιτίας της  οποίας  λατρευόταν ως Άρια, διαφοροποιούνταν από τον χαρακτήρα του Άρη, το θεό του πολέμου. Ο Άρης αντιπροσώπευε αναρχικές διαμάχες, την βία του πολέμου, ενώ η Αθηνά πιστευόταν ότι είχε διδάξει στην ανθρωπότητα τις τεχνικές και τους κανόνες του πολέμου. Ως αποτέλεσμα, τα δυο αδέλφια συχνά περιγράφονταν από αρχαίους συγγραφείς σε μια κατάσταση διαμάχης και αυτό ήταν ιδιαίτερα αληθινό κατά την διάρκεια του Τρωικού πολέμου.
>
> ---
>
> The combative nature of Athena because of which she was worshipped, **differentiated from the nature of Ares**, the god of war. **Ares represented anarchist struggles, the violence of war**, **while Athena was believed to have taught mankind the techniques and the rules of war**. As a result, the two brothers often were described by ancient writers in a conflict situation and that was especially true during the Trojan war.
>
> <sub>[Ekivolos.gr](http://www.ekivolos.gr/H%20thrhskeia%20twn%20arxaiwn%20ellhnwn.htm)</sub>

[Ares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares) never became a patron god and was not worshipped as much as the other gods initially, although he was established as a god of the [Dodekatheon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenism_%28religion%29) later on, tied to people who had tough and violent customs:

> Όπως ήταν φυσικό, καμιά πόλη δεν τον έκανε πολιούχο της ενώ δεν ήταν ιδιαίτερα αγαπητός και στον κύκλο των υπολοίπων θεών. Για τους αρχαίους Έλληνες ο Άρης ήταν η κυρίαρχη φιγούρα πίσω από την βία, τις μάχες και τις άλλες διαμάχες μεταξύ των ανδρών.  Η «αίρεση» και η συνακόλουθη λατρεία  του θεού μάλλον άρχισε στην Θράκη όπου σύμφωνα με τον Όμηρο ζούσε ο Άρης. Από εκεί η λατρεία  του εξαπλώθηκε στην Βοιωτία και μετά σε ολόκληρη την Ελλάδα ολοκληρωτικά, οδηγώντας στην καθιέρωση του Άρη ως ενός  από τους δώδεκα θεούς του Ολύμπου. Οι ιδιότητες του Άρη συνδέονται με τις ρίζες του αφού, για τους αρχαίους Έλληνες, η Θράκη ήταν ένα μέρος σκληρών ανθρώπων και εθίμων.
>
> ---
>
> Naturally, no city made him a patron god and he was not as popular as the other gods. For the ancient Greeks Ares was the dominant figure behind violence, battles and other conflicts among men. The "heresy" and the subsequent worship of God began in Thrace [*a region in Northern Greece*] where, according to Homer, Ares lived. From there, the cult spread to Viotia [*Another region of Greece*] and then throughout Greece completely, leading to the establishment of Ares as one of the twelve gods of Olympus. The properties of Ares were associated with its roots since, for the ancient Greeks, **Thrace was a place of hard people and customs.**
>
> <sub>[Ekivolos.gr](http://www.ekivolos.gr/H%20thrhskeia%20twn%20arxaiwn%20ellhnwn.htm)</sub>

It should be noted, that ancient Greeks had two war gods in order to demonstrate that a subtle technique of conducting war is a lot more efficient than brute force.

> Σε αντίθεση με την Αθηνά που επινοούσε μεθοδικούς τρόπους για να κηρύττει και να διεξάγει  πόλεμο, ο Άρης αγαπούσε τις αιματοχυσίες και τις χαοτικές μάχες. Στον Τρωικό πόλεμο, ο Άρης τραυματίστηκε σοβαρά από την Αθηνά καθώς βοηθούσε τους Τρώες, αποδεικνύοντας έτσι ότι η τεχνική ήταν ικανή να υπερνικήσει την ωμή βία.
>
> ---
>
> Unlike Athena who invented methodical ways to preach and to conduct war, Ares loved bloodshed and chaotic battles. In the Trojan war, Ares was seriously injured by Athena as he was helping the Trojans, **thus proving that technique was able to overcome brute force.**
>
> <sub>[Ekivolos.gr](http://www.ekivolos.gr/H%20thrhskeia%20twn%20arxaiwn%20ellhnwn.htm)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

the answer is the question. Athena made plans of conquest before each battle.
Ares just fought, because he was bloodthirsty.